# perl regex find and replace with variable from bash

Tags: regex, bash, perl, command-line

I have this regex: `'src=\d'` which match all src attributes who start with a number in a file.  I need to store it within a variable, cut `src=` out and write from there a new `$string` with `\d` concatenated to it: `$string . $d`. Is it possible to store only `\d` in a variable with a single command line? How to use `cut` and variable in a command line with perl? Is it possible?

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/src="\d+/src="http:\/\/website.com\/\d+/g’ file.tsv
```

Comment: Am I correct to assume that `src=d` is a typo `src=\d`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but I think you want something like this, where the `()` brackets store the number and the `$1` replaces it back.

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/src="(\d+)/src="http:\/\/website.com\/$1/g’ file.tsv
```

And you can avoid the so-called 'leaning toothpick syndrome by selecting a different delimiter for the `s///` operation like `s{}{}`

```
perl -pi -w -e 's{src="(\d+)}{src="http://website.com/$1}g’ file.tsv
```

Comment: Yes, it is! I had tried this but without `()` brackets.. It only needs to be correct in the regex that is \d or \d+

Comment: @lizardhr - just change the `d+` to `\d+`